# Pointers in C: Is cell=&num equivalent to *cell=num?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Suppose you have the variable `int num` and the pointer `int* cell`. Does it make a difference for the values stored in `cell` and `num` to write `cell = &num` or `*cell = num`?

Comment: Having assigned the pointer with `cell = &num` there is little point then having `*cell = num` since `*cell` is already `num`. Where you have `&num` that is the address where the variable `num` resides. When you have `num` that is the variable's value.

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. Note that asking particular questions will not get you anywhere in C programming. You need to get the concepts right. You really should read a good C book and not skip chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell = &num
```

means that the contents/value of cell will be equal to the address of num.

```
*cell = num
```

means that the content at the address stored in cell, that is the value to which the pointer is pointing to, will be equal to the value of num.

Comment: Address of cell won't be equal to that of num. But the value (or contents) of cell will equal to the address of num.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes you are correct. my bad, it has been really long time since I touched c. I will edit my answer :)

Comment: can you do the same for the second part too? *Contents at the address stored in cell*